# Unmerged cell with text centered across selection appears warped

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I center text across selection, I get this warped-looking text (see below) when I scroll away from the page then coming back to it. Any idea what is causing this? I'm trying to stay away from merging cells in Excel because of all those nasty stories you hear about when merged cells are involved.

[image: Warped Text]

How I get around it every single time is by highlighting them (but it just re-appears whenever I scroll across the sheet).

[image: How it's supposed to look like]

I've always assumed that it's a glitch on the development side so I just ignored it. It's slowly getting on my nerve so I thought it'd be better to give it a shot here and see if any of you have experienced this before. Appreciate any help or workaround you have in mind!

Comment: *Warped*? Do you mean **wrapped**? Have no idea what "*nasty stories*" you are referring to. I use merged cells all the time without issue. It looks to me like you have more text than will fit in the cell, then when you center it, the text overlaps into other cells. Does it look normal if you enlarge the cell to contain the text? Have you tried word wrap?

Comment: @CharlieRB No I do mean warped. I've edited the question to show how it looks like when i do the temporary fix. The cell involved already has word wrap turned on too.

Comment: Are all updates installed for the OS and for the Office Suite? Does this file exhibit the same problems on other computers?

Comment: @CharlieRB Not sure about the updates but I'm guessing they are since they are used for work (I have no admin rights to the computer). Yes it still happens on my coworkers' computers.

Comment: Since it occurs on other computers, it sounds like file corruption. Try creating a new file to see if the problem still exists. This will isolate if it is a file or program problem.

Comment: @CharlieRB I just tried copying into a new workbook but the problem still persist. Maybe I do have to use merging after all just to avoid this glitch...